# Wrong GridView total rows count

Tags: yii2

I'm getting a weird result.
In my CustomerQuery i have some filters applied before the all() function.

(like

```
$this->andWhere(['profiles.type'=>'f']);
```

)

The filter gets applied before every *find()->all()*, but in the pagination count before the gridview it states
Showing 1-6 of **12** elements
If i check the query with Yii's debugger, i can see the count query used by yii to determine the number of elements is missing the *profiles.type = "f"* while the actual query doesn't.

Is this a bug? Is there another function i need to use instead of andWhere to apply the same filter to the count query?

Comment: you need to add more code here add complete search method from your `SearchModel` and the view where you are using the `GridView`

Comment: All the code you are asking is the standard gii generated code. And i strongly doubt there's a problem in the code every yii programmer uses.
The problem is the line i showed. If i add the same line on ProfileQuery->init() it works like expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems this in expected result (i'd expect and definitely prefer the count function to execute the exact same query, though).

To apply the same filter/where to both the real query and the count query you have to override the ActiveQuery's count method.
Here's an example

```
class ProfileQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery{
...
    public function standardFilters(){
        $this->andWhere(['not',['table_name.status'=>2]]);
    }

    public function all($db = null){
        $this->standardFilters();
        return parent::all($db);
    }
public function count($q = '*', $db = null) {
    $this->standardFilters();
    return parent::count($q, $db);
}
...
```